# How can i edit on double click inside table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sneh_pandya/48MRf/3/#&togetherjs=2SPzouR4D6), I have the prompt on every `td` in side the `table`, but the working is only on the header , u can see in fiddle.

**What i want:**

I want to edit inside the table using same double click,`(same as it works for the header)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate the dblclick:

```
$("#lst_Regions").on( 'dblclick', 'td', function (){
   //code here
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48MRf/7/)

Comment: thank you..what if i want to edit at the same place..rather using prompt?

Comment: Than you can add an input text and make it without border and background color so that it will look like plain text.